# Ansible winrm программа не удаляется на Windows 10

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-playbook

Всем привет! Настраиваю аркестрацию Windows при помощи Ansible. Пытаюсь сделать первый этап, удаление установленной программы с Windows.

Всё настроил, проверил, на Windows создаётся директория после запуска ansible, но после таски по удалению софта с Windows ничего не происходит, софт остаётся на ОС Windows

Мой playbook

```
---

- name: Example
  hosts: windows
  tasks:
     - name: Create directory
       win_file:
         path: d:\roschat
         state: directory

     - name: Get exe file from ftp
       win_get_url:
         url: ftp://10.10.199.31/releases/RosChat/client/roschat-client/01.06.2020_10%3A27_0.1-1143/windows/x64/roschat-0.1.1143.x64.exe
         dest: d:\roschat

     - name: Uninstall roschat
       win_package:
         path: "C:\\Program Files\\roschat\\Uninstall РосЧат.exe"
         productid: '56e2ec90-1579-5edf-8225-77cb72eed1a1'
         arguments: /allusers /S
         state: absent
```

Уже перепробовал множество вариантов, но ПО так и не удаляется( Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Получилось удалить 7-Zip таким способом. Значит где-то, что-то не так пишу или делаю при удалении этой программы

Comment: Установщик можно куда-нить залить? По кофейной гуще трудно гадать.

Comment: Да, можно скачать по [ссылке](https://yadi.sk/d/QoG4t22vW6o_8w)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался наконец-то. 2 дня гугления не прошли даром) Похоже дело было в правах на выполнение команд. Нужно было выполнять команды PowerShell от имени администратора. Мой финальный playbook

```
---

- name: Update windows x64 client
  hosts: windows
  tasks:
     - name: Create temp directory
       win_file:
         path: d:\roschat
         state: directory

     - name: Get exe file from ftp
       win_get_url:
         url: ftp://10.10.199.31/releases/RosChat/client/roschat-client/01.06.2020_10%3A27_0.1-1143/windows/x64/roschat-0.1.1143.x64.exe
         dest: d:\roschat

     - name: Update roschat client
       win_shell: |
         If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

         {
           $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
           Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
           Break
         }
         $roschat  = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "РосЧат" } | Select-Object -Property UninstallString
         $roschat = $roschat.UninstallString.Replace('{',' ').Replace('}',' ').Replace('/allusers','')
         if($roschat){
          Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $roschat -ArgumentList '/Queit /allusers /S /All'
         }
         Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'D:\roschat\roschat-*.x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/Queit /S'

     - name: Delete temp directory
       win_file:
         path: d:\roschat
         state: absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Пошёл другим путём. Получилось удалить при помощи PowerShell

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\roschat\Uninstall РосЧат.exe' -ArgumentList '/Queit /allusers /S /All'
```

Отключил для учётной записи UAC.

На Windows 10 команда отрабатывает и программа удаляется. Через Ansible программа не удаляется, хотя и выполняется

```
TASK [Uninstall roschat] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/windows/playbooks/windows.yml:18
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.10.225.189> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: bezpa on PORT 5986 TO 10.10.225.189
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [10.10.225.189] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath \"C:\\Program Files\\roschat\\Uninstall.exe\" -ArgumentList '/Queit /allusers /S /All'",
    "delta": "0:00:00.416690",
    "end": "2020-06-02 10:19:11.953841",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-06-02 10:19:11.537150",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

Переименовал файл, убрал русские буквы, но программа всё равно не удаляется.

Но 7-Zip через Ansible при выполнении этой же команды отлично удаляется. Как такое может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Через стандартный модуль `win_package` не поехало. Скажи "спасибо" разрабам за то, что используют какое-то палево, а не [msi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_Windows). 7-zip, кстати использует именно его, поэтому там проблем не возникло.

```yaml
---
  - name: Uninstall roschat
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    serial:
      - "100%"
    vars:
      roschat_state: absent
    tasks:

    - name: Uninstall roschat 4 Windows
      when:
        - ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
        - roschat_state == 'absent'
      become: yes
      become_method: runas
      become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
      block:
        - win_stat:
            path: '{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\roschat\Uninstall РосЧат.exe'
          register: roschat_installed_state
        - win_shell: cmd.exe /k "Uninstall РосЧат.exe" /S
          args:
            chdir: '{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\roschat'
          when: roschat_installed_state.stat.exists == true
      tags:
        - windows
        - uninstall
```

P.S. Идемпотентность в комплекте, кстати.

Comment: Вы уже не первый, кто отозвался о качестве софта. Спасибо, завтра попробую ваш вариант)